# How to read/write XML to TcpStream in Rust?

Tags: xml, rust

I'm trying to log in to a server using Rust and XML. I use the `TcpStream` struct within a `Connect` struct I defined:

```rust
//use std::fs;

mod epp {
    use crate::Config;
    use std::io::Result;
    use std::io::{self, Read, Write};
    use std::net::TcpStream;
    //use openssl::ssl::{SslMethod, SslConnector, SslStream};

    pub struct Connect {
        stream: TcpStream,
    }

    impl Connect {
        pub fn new(config: Config) -> Connect {
            let mut server = config.epp_test_server;

            server.push_str(":49160");

            let stream = TcpStream::connect(server).unwrap();

            //Do an initial read to flush out responses (make way for subsequent reads).
            let mut data = [0 as u8; 11024]; 
            let result = stream.read(&mut data);
            Connect { stream }
        }

        pub fn write_all(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) {
            self.stream
                .write_all(buf)
                .expect("Could not write XML to SslStream");
        }

        pub fn flush(&mut self) {
            self.stream.flush().unwrap();
        }

        pub fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<String> {
            match self.stream.read(buf) {
                Ok(_) => {
                    let text = String::from_utf8_lossy(&buf[..]);
                    Ok(text.to_string())
                }
                Err(e) => match e.kind() {
                    io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock => {
                        println!("Got WouldBlock error. There looks like nothing to read.");
                        Err(e)
                    }
                    _ => panic!("Got an error {}", e),
                },
            }
        }
    }
}

pub struct Config {
    epp_test_server: String,
}

impl Config {
    pub fn new() -> Config {
        Config {
            epp_test_server: String::from("139.162.247.141"),
        }
    }
}
fn main() {
    let config: Config = Config::new();
    let mut stream = epp::Connect::new(config);
    //let xml = fs::read_to_string("login.xml").expect("Could not load file.");


    let xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<epp xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0\"
   xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"
   xsi:schemaLocation=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0 epp-1.0.xsd\">
<command>
  <login>
    <clID>**TAG**</clID>
    <pw>**Password**</pw>
    <options>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <lang>en</lang>
    </options>
    <svcs>
       <objURI>urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0</objURI>
       <objURI>urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:contact-1.0</objURI>
       <objURI>urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:host-1.0</objURI>
    </svcs>
  </login>
  <clTRID>ABC-12345</clTRID>
</command></epp>";
    xml = format!("{}\r\n", xml);
    stream.write_all(xml.as_bytes());
    stream.flush();

    let mut data = [0 as u8; 11024];
    let result = stream.read(&mut data).unwrap();

    println!("EPP Query result: {}", result);
}
```

It seems to write fine but I'm not getting the desired response. The write functionality can be demonstrated using netcat (here on server 139.162.247.141 port 49160) - `nc -l 139.162.247.141 49160`.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: From inspection, your code is presumably spewing *pages* of warnings about unused results. **Don't ignore warnings, especially when trying to debug a problem**.

Comment: @Shepmaster Many thanks for input. Do you know of a test EPP server that I could exchange XML with (the only way I'll get it to run on Rust Playground)?

Comment: I honestly don't even know what "EPP" means! However, your question presumably doesn't need any such thing. You state that "does not write the XML", which is easy enough to demonstrate by connecting to a basic TCP server like `netcat`.

Comment: I've changed to reproducible code as requested. The listening server is not set up yet, will set one up.

Comment: I've set up the server but its snipping the xml sent.

Comment: I tried your code against a netcat server and the XML _is_ sent completely. Note however that there is no newline at the end, could that be what confuses your server?

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding `xml = format!("{}\r\n", xml);` but no luck.

Comment: Ok, it looks like it's working, I'm just not receiving the response I expect. @Jmb do you see anything wrong with the read code after the write_all code?

Comment: Well, your read code may return a truncated result. Depending on the particulars of the EPP protocol, you might be better off with [`read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_string) or [`read_to_end`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_end) or directly giving `stream` to whatever you intend to use to deserialize the returned XML.

Comment: Both `read_to_string` and `read_to_end` just hang.

Comment: @Jmb Many thanks for your help. It looks like it's working now.